# generate proto file from xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, protobuf-net

I have an xsd file and I want to generate proto file from it.
First of all, I used **xsd.exe** to generate C# classes from xsd file and now I want to generate proto files.
I know that I have to use `string proto = Serializer.GetProto<MyType>();`  but it seems not working because the auto-generated C# classes are not decorated with attributes.
Is there an other way to generate proto file without adding these attributes to the generated code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protobuf-net can use types decorated with `[DataContract]` / `[DataMember]`, *as long as* the `[DataMember]`s include a suitable `Order = n` optional parameter. From memory, xsd does include this, *but* it starts the `Order` at zero, where-as protobuf-net wants to start at one (since zero is not a valid tag in protobuf). The easiest fix to this is to create a second separate file to add a patch in a `partial class`:

```
namespace TheSameNamespace {
    [ProtoContract(DataMemberOffset = 1)]
    partial class TheSameClass {}
}
```

This tells protobuf-net to add one to all `[DataMember(Order = n)]` markers. After that: it should work.